# How to increase the height of the drop-down menu in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a screenshot below which I have to replicate in HTML, CSS and JS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/23/embedded/result/).

The HTML and CSS codes which I have used for the drop-down menu is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <div style="">
            <img tabindex="1" src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">View Status</a><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#">Release Bills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add Attendee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export as</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View in Google Sheets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Send Notifications</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.nav-top-searchbar {
    position: relative;
}

#ellipsis {
    top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 43px;
}

#ellipsis:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#ellipsis:focus+.dropdown {
    display: block;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    background: #10314c;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
    padding-left: 2%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 10;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.dropdown a {
    color: #676767;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.dropdown li:hover {
    background-color: #EDEDED;
}

.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

The problem in my fiddle is if I click on the three dots, the drop-down starts from the bottom section of the search bar.

I am wondering what changes `I need to do in the CSS code so that it starts from the upper section of the search bar` as marked in the arrow sign of the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `padding-top` and `top:2px` to move it up to start from the upper section , and add a `cursor: pointer;` to the `elipsis` ( not necessary but good ) , you can add `padding-bottom` to add space after the last text and add some shadow with `box-shadow` to make it pop, here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/31/

Comment: Looks good. One quick question, Is there any way I can increase space after send notifications text ? If I see the screenshot, there is a space after the send notifications text. Is there any way I can increase that spacing ?

Comment: yeah, add a padding-bottom and remove the height so it becomes dynamic ( and add shadow )  https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/31/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `padding-top: 20px;` to the `.dropdown` selector achieves the result for me.

Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pj974ot/)

Comment: I tried. It seems like the drop-down contents seems to go off from the menu. Can you update it in the fiddle ?

Comment: It still start from the bottom section of the search-bar.